# Root-relative links in HTML sites that work both locally and on the web

Tags: html, file, browser, hyperlink, relative-path

Root-relative links are usually accomplished by prefacing a `href` attribute with `/`, like so:

```html
<a href="/path_to_file">
```

The problem is that this doesn't work with locally run sites, as the `/` will link to actual root of the computer's filesystem rather than the website's base URL.

Is there a way to make root-relative links that function properly not only in traditional web-hosted cases but also when run locally?

Comment: This is a non-answer, so I'll leave this as a comment. A more convenient way to deal with this is to run a simple local webserver that serves your files. Instead of using file:///, you would use http://localhost:1234/. Might make development a lot easier. There's very simple scripts that can do this for you, if you need a recomendation, let me know what your platform is.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a base URI in the `head`:

```html
<base href="https://example.com/" />
```

With this `base` element, `<a href="/path_to_file">` will link to `https://example.com/path_to_file`, no matter the current document host.